# 2 Listagg the same query and repeated value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, listagg

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
         ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY A.f_NAME ASC) AS r,
         A.ID,
         A.F_NAME,
         A.L_NAME,
         A.FATHER_NAME,
         A.DOB,
         A.DEAD_DATE,
         A.GENDER,
         A.NATIONALITY,
         A.AUTHOR_INFO,
         A.REWARD,
         LISTAGG (TO_CHAR (S.SUBJECT_NAME), ', ')
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TO_CHAR (S.SUBJECT_NAME))
            AS SUBJECT_NAME,
         LISTAGG (TO_CHAR (B.TITLE), ', ')
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TO_CHAR (b.title))
            AS book
    FROM book_author ba
         RIGHT JOIN author a
            ON A.ID = BA.AUTHOR_ID
         LEFT JOIN book b
            ON B.ID = BA.BOOK_ID
         LEFT JOIN author_subject ass
            ON a.ID = ass.author_id
         LEFT JOIN subjects s
            ON s.id = ass.subject_id
   WHERE A.ACTIVE = 1
GROUP BY A.ID,
         A.F_NAME,
         A.L_NAME,
         A.FATHER_NAME,
         A.DOB,
         A.DEAD_DATE,
         A.GENDER,
         A.NATIONALITY,
         A.AUTHOR_INFO,
         A.REWARD;
```

*If  1 subject 2 books,  then the  subject repeated 2 time . I know this question repeated, but do not write correctly.
Please help me. Thanks. **18c and earlier Oracle***

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could simplify the query in the question so it is simpler to answer.  Your query is way more complicated than necessary to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `row_number()` to do what you want.  Your query is quite complicated, but here is the idea:

```
with x as (
      <whatever>
     )
select <grouping columns>, -- grouping columns
       list_agg(case when seqnum_subject_name = 1 then subject_name end, ', ') within group (order by subject_name),
       list_agg(case when seqnum_title = 1 then title end, ', ') within group (order by title)
from (select x.*,
             row_number() over (partition by <grouping columns>, subject_name order by subject_name) as seqnum_subject_name,
             row_number() over (partition by <grouping columns>, title order by title) as seqnum_title
      from x
     ) x
group by <grouping columns>;
```

I am not sure why you are converting `subject_name` to a string.  I don't see why that would be needed so I removed that logic.